# Adding new column based on when the value changes in another column

Tags: sql

I need to execute a query where I want to create a new column that finds at which date the payment_date changes corresponding to a given issue_date. For instance, in the screenshot, you will notice the payment_date for issue_date '2021-07-20' is '2021-07-10'. Based on the data, I want to create a new column that is able to figure out at which issue_date the payment_date changes. So for this example, the payment date changes to '2021-07-24' at the issue_date of '2021-07-23', and I want to create a new column that displays the date of '2021-07-23' to correspond to the issue_date of 2021-07-20 as paymentmade_date. For dates '2021-07-21' and '2021-07-22', the payment_date is the same at '2021-07-10', so these values should be blank in the new paymentmade_date column.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpwJu.png

Current query:

```
select t1.lease_number ,t2.rec_bal, to_date(t2.date_dim_id,'YYYYMMDD') as issue_date,t2.paid_to as payment_date,remain_months_upd,remaining_pymt_periods, t2.dealer_dim_id, t2.lease_contract_dim_id
from dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_lease_contract_dim t1
, dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_lease_transaction_fact t2
where t1.lease_contract_dim_id=t2.lease_contract_dim_id
and t2.date_dim_id >=20210301 
and lease_number in (1724065)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using sql server 2012 or newer, you can use the LAG() function. this is quick and dirty but it should give you want you want and you can build from here.

```
create table test (issue_date date, payment_date date)

insert test
select '7/20/21','7/10/21'
union all
select '7/21/21','7/10/21'
union all
select '7/22/21','7/10/21'
union all
select '7/23/21','7/24/21'

select *, case when payment_date <> lag(payment_date) over (order by issue_date) then issue_date end as paymentmade_date
from test
```